# insufficient permission error due t scope

Tags: javascript, html, url-rewriting, google-api, google-drive-api

I encounter the following error in console while trying to execute my code:

```
 POST https://content.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?alt=json&key=AIzaSyB3BGJskI7cJUvnl7jzjiX4eh86K9sldgA 403 (Forbidden)
```

I am using google URL Shortner API, and feel that the issue is derived from insufficient permission as shown by the error in details:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Below is the part of the code that I think affects it:

```
/ The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'ID';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'ID';
      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,

              'immediate': true
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }
```

In particular,

'scope': scope,

I have been struggling with this issue for a while and is looking for a soluton.

Comment: I'm not familiar with google's api, however usually scope in an oauth / 3-legged approach refers to some type of permissions like "read" or "write" not an array of urls?

Comment: thank you for your response. Initially this code was generated to only work with photos from drive, but I want to use it to be able to grab and write pdf documents as well